# DB2 Error SQLCODE=-103, SQLSTATE=42604

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I am trying to update a table, but it isn't working and giving this sql error.

```
//Updating Buy Table
Integer stkbid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("stockBid"));
System.out.println("stock buy id : " + stkbid);
//get buy details
PreparedStatement stmtbuy = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT \"StockSymbol\", \"Unit\", \"Price\", \"ClearingFee\", \"StampDuty\", \"BrokerFee\""  + 
        "FROM SPM.\"StockBuy\" WHERE \"StockBuyId\" = '"+ stkbid + "'");

System.out.println("Got stock buy details");

ResultSet rs=stmtbuy.executeQuery();
rs.next();
//String stkcode = rs.getString("StockSymbol");
Integer stkunit =  Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Unit"));
stkunit -= stock.getStockUnit();
Double stkprice = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("Price"));
Double stkclear = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("ClearingFee"));
Double stksd = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("StampDuty"));
Double stkbfee = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("BrokerFee"));
Double stkval = stkunit * stkprice;
Double stknv = stkval + stkval * (stkclear + stksd + stkbfee);

System.out.println(stknv);

PreparedStatement stmtbuy1 = conn.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE SPM.\"StockBuy\" SET \"Unit\" = " + stkunit + ", \"Value\" = " + stkval + ", \"NetValue\" = " + stknv + 
        "WHERE \"StockBuyId\" = "+ stkbid);
```

Comment: the first select statement is working and also i tried the same format of enclosing stkbid within single quotes but in the update statement it is not working

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using parameterized queries?

Comment: Yes i could use it but this should work too no ?

Comment: -103 means "constant IS AN INVALID NUMERIC CONSTANT": http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn103.htm

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to construct full sql queries like you did. Use placeholders in PreparedStatements, like shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Perhaps you need a blank before the word `WHERE` in your update string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a space in before the `WHERE` clause, which messed up your `stknv`.

```
" WHERE \"StockBuyId\" = "+ stkbid);
```

I think it's an obligation of any poster to remind you that you should use parametrized query. So I shall do the same.

"**Please use parametrized query!**"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that mistake and yes using parametrised query solved my problem..

Answer (score 1):

The query that is works has a quote at the end:

```
" WHERE \"StockBuyId\" = '"+ stkbid + "'");
```

The one that fails does not

```
    "WHERE \"StockBuyId\" = "+ stkbid);
```

That might have something to do with it.